# Not able to sort, getting error

Tags: ember.js

I am trying  to sort my model. But getting a error as

```
Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

any one help me to sort this out? I guess that `model` is not existing in `Computed` methods.

here is my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [{"name":"fruit"},{"name":"flowers"}]
  },
  sortingByKey:['date'],
  sorter:Ember.Computed.sort("model","sortingByKey"), 
  init(){
    var sort = this.get("sorter");
  }
});
```

[Twiddle Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Ember.computed` instead of `Ember.Computed`. error says that `Ember.Computed` is undefined.

In your code there are some issues,
1. `model` is property will be available in controller(which will be set by setupController
2. You can't do this in `this.get("sorter")`.
3. `date` property is not there in `model`

Comment: I have updated my code as like your suggession. But still  not getting the model sorted. https://ember-twiddle.com/60d4c12e0004aa54ee1f2be16a74a8ce?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

Comment: if I am wrong, can you please show me the right way to sort here?

Comment: Actually I pointed out everything. any how you can just have look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cd74d2102a0b10d9c2c4d11f9e4bd249?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: This question should be closed as a typo.